# Identify beamer theme of presentation

Tags: beamer, themes

Does someone recognize the beamer theme used in [this presentation](http://iphome.hhi.de/schwarz/assets/dc/07-DictionaryCoding.pdf)?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to match it using this site: https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/